# Name of trope where the character briefly defies laws of nature/physics?

Tags: trope

Is there a trope for when a character defies the laws of physics/nature, but doesn't realize it for a moment, and so, because of this, the laws of nature don't take effect immediately, but only until after the character becomes aware of their situation?

Example: Dog chases cat. Dog accidentally runs off a cliff but doesn't notice the ground beneath it is gone. Dog stands in mid air for a moment. Dog realizes it's floating in air. Dog falls to the ground.

Comment: [Gravity is a Harsh Mistress](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GravityIsAHarshMistress)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often called [Toon Physics](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ToonPhysics)  or Cartoon Physics.